# Lost to find a topic for my reseach!

Tags: phd, research-topic

I am really LOST. anyone can help me sharing his/her experience would be great.

I am currently a PhD student and I changed my advisor and minor 'research field' after one year of my program. This is a new research field to mine but I have the ability and confident to conduct research and go through but the big problem I've never been exposed to this field before and couldn't find a solid topic/idea to consider for my research. my advisor asks me to find a topic in my own. any tips guys!!

Comment: There is a lot of existing advice on this site; see the [tag:research-topic] tag for examples. Read these, try their suggestions, then if you find that they don't help you, come back and [edit] your question to explain what you've tried and why it didn't help.